# Perl generate random session id for high traffic

Tags: perl

I am trying to generate a random id for sessions cookie for every user session in Perl. Of course I searched cpan and google and found many similar topics and same weakness. The most modules used are [Digest::SHA](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Digest%3A%3ASHA&mode=all) and [Data::UUID](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Data%3A%3AUUID&mode=all) and the module [Data::GUID](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Data%3A%3AGUID&mode=all) which internally uses Data::UUID.

Here is the code I can summarize the most methods used in modules on cpan:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.10;

use Digest::SHA;
use Data::UUID;
use Data::GUID;# uses Data::UUID internally, so no need for it
use Time::HiRes ();

for (1..10) {
    #say generate_sha(1); # 1= 40 bytes, 256=64 bytes, 512=128 bytes, 512224, 512256 
    say generate_uuid();
    #say generate_guid();
}

sub generate_sha {
    my ($bits) = @_;
    # SHA-1/224/256/384/512
    return Digest::SHA -> new($bits) -> add($$, +{}, Time::HiRes::time(), rand(Time::HiRes::time()) ) -> hexdigest;
}

sub generate_uuid {
    return Data::UUID->new->create_hex(); #create_str, create_b64
}

sub generate_guid {
    # uses Data::UUID internally 
    return Data::GUID->guid;
}
```

Here is a sample output form Data::UUID module:

```
0x0217C34C6C0710149FE4C7FBB6FA663B
0x0218665F6C0710149FE4C7FBB6FA663B
0x0218781A6C0710149FE4C7FBB6FA663B
0x021889316C0710149FE4C7FBB6FA663B
0x021899E16C0710149FE4C7FBB6FA663B
0x0218AB2B6C0710149FE4C7FBB6FA663B
0x0218BB1D6C0710149FE4C7FBB6FA663B
0x0218CABD6C0710149FE4C7FBB6FA663B
0x0218DB786C0710149FE4C7FBB6FA663B
0x0218ED396C0710149FE4C7FBB6FA663B
```

The id's generated from these seems to be unique, but what I am concerning is about high traffic or concurrency, say what if a 1000 only not saying 1000,000 users connected at the same time either from the same process like running under FCGI (say each FCGI process serving only 10 users) or from separate processes like running under CGI mode.

In the SHA I used this random string:

```
($$, +{}, Time::HiRes::time(), rand(Time::HiRes::time())
```

it includes Anonymous hash reference address and the current time in microseconds with [Time::HiRes::time](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Time%3A%3AHiRes&mode=all). Is there any other ways to make random string.

I have read topics to add the Host name and IP address of the remote user but others say about proxies could be used.

I see [Plack::Session::State](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Plack%3A%3ASession%3A%3AState&mode=all) module uses this simple code to generate id's:

```
Digest::SHA1::sha1_hex(rand() . $$ . {} . time)
```

So the question in short I want to generate a unique may be up to 64 bytes long session id guaranteed to work with high traffic.

Comment: You're worried about conflicts with only 1000 concurrent users?

Comment: I am worried in general, I am saying high traffic but give the 1000 as example and did not exaggerate saying 100_000 or 1000_000 concurrent users. I am wondering basically if you have say 100 FCGI process, each one just serving 5 users, how will the random id generator will work?

Comment: Re "The id's generated from these seems to be unique", Let's assume they are. That's still not good enough. They almost always need to be unpredictable as well.

Comment: `rand(Time::HiRes::time())` doesn't make any sense. Could just as easily say `rand(1400000000)`, which begs the question: Why that number??? Use `rand()` or `pack('d',rand())`.

Comment: @ikegami why it does not make any sense? this returns the time in microseconds means a good chance for random string.

Comment: As I understand, `rand` or `rand 1` should be equally good as `rand(Time::HiRes::time())`, as `Time::HiRes::time()` doesn't contribute to more randomness (just sets upper limit for random number).

Comment: @ikegami I wish I knew more about predictability and being able to determine next values.  Do you have any good sources that talk about the matter?  As I understand it, using RSA or higher bit SHA are the more secure hashes.

Comment: @daliaessam because `rand` is a set table.  The numbers may be different, but the predictability is the same.

Comment: @daliaessam, Multiplying a random number by another relatively constant number (~1400000000) doesn't add randomness.

Comment: (Also, `rand` takes an integer argument, so it's the time in seconds.)

Comment: @vol7ron, You can clearly see that knowing one of the OP's Data::UUID allows one to guess the next one by incrementing a part of the UUID. A hash (e.g. SHA) would do the trick.

Comment: If you print `Time::HiRes::time()` you get a number like `1408376135.11733`, where the `1408376135`-part is the seconds since way back, and `.11733` is the micro(?) seconds. So the first part of this number will be mainly predictable and common to most sessions created in the same second. I would focus on the fractional part. I.e. `$h=Time::HiRes::time();print sprintf('%X',  $$*(+{})*($h-int($h))*rand(1E7) )`

Answer (score 3):

You can safely use `Data::UUID` and you shouldn't be concerned about duplicates, you will not encounter them.

Also `rand()` will not return the same number when called subsequently even under assumption that it is called at the same moment of time. A pseudo random algorithm generates the next number based on its current state and the previously generated values. A true random generator is generally not used alone but in conjunction with a pseudo random number generator. In either case the likelihood of subsequently generated numbers to repeat between the nearest clock ticks in practical terms is negligible. In your example you may want to use `rand(2**32)`.